# Can't display attribute of object session on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I can't read the attribute of the object which send through the session on JSP file. I tried with expression language but it only works with int type Attribute, not effect with String attribute :(

**jsp file**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ include file="/common/tablib.jsp"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ page session="true"%>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <c:if test="${ not empty usermodel }">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href='#'>
                            ${usermodel.id} </a></li> <!-- it works -->

                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href='#'>
                            ${usermodel.fullname} </a></li> <!-- it doesn't work -->

                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link"
                        href='<c:url value="/logout?action=logout"/>'>Logout </a></li>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${ empty usermodel }">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link"
                        href='<c:url value="/login?action=login"/>'>Login </a></li>
                </c:if>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**java file**

```
    package controller.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.NewsModel;
import model.UserModel;
import service.ICategoryService;
import service.INewsService;
import service.IUserService;
import utils.FormUtil;
import utils.SessionUtil;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/homepage", "/login","/logout"})
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3500762834657105845L;

    @Inject
    private ICategoryService categoryService;
    @Inject
    private INewsService newsService;
    @Inject
    private IUserService userService;


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = req.getParameter("action");
        if (action != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("login")) {
            UserModel model = FormUtil.toModel(UserModel.class, req);
            model = userService.findByUsernameAndPasswordAndStatus(model.getUserName(), model.getPassword(), 1);
            if (model != null) {
                SessionUtil.getInstance().putValue(req, "usermodel", model);
                String test=model.getFullName();
                SessionUtil.getInstance().putValue(req, "test", test);
                if (model.getRole().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("USER")) {
                    resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/homepage");
                } else if (model.getRole().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
                    resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/adminhomepage");
                }
            } else {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login?action=login");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

**debugging image**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBPjr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyxEJ.png)

It seems like has problem with the String attribute like fullname or password, but no probkem with int attribute like id?

Comment: maybe a typo here can you change `${usermodel.fullname}` to `${usermodel.fullName}` and check onces.

Comment: @Swati omg it works, thank you so much. I thought this name must same with name in database but it not true.